# .htaccess not redirecting to www

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect any traffic to the http://www. version of my webpage.

My .htaccess file contains the following and nothing else:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is not redirecting from non www. to the www. version?

Comment: Have you verified that the  .htaccess is parsed at all? Do you have access to the main apache .conf files? If so, you would need to ensure `AllowOverride all` is present for the VirtualHost or Directory to enable the use of .htaccess at all.  A quick way to check would be to put something invalid in that .htaccess and see if it results in a 500 error. If not, then the .htaccess was probably not read by Apache.

Comment: It looks ok to me. Is your htaccess file being read? A qiuck test would be to put some random text at the top of your htaccess file and then try your site. If it causes a 500 error then it's being read otherwise it's not.

Comment: Looks like it is not being read. I am hosting on Godaddy if that helps? I can ask on there live chat, but if anyone knows an obvious reason then that would be great?

Comment: Nope talk to go daddy and get them to fix it for you as @MichaelBerkowski said.